# Unity 3D Text becomes Word Cubes

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, vuforia

As the image shows, my 3D Text keeps disappearing from my scene when I click Play, and then when I zoom in, this is what I see.

When I exit the Play scene, it stays like that till I `Ctrl+S` and Save on which is returns to its proper text form.

Is there something I don't know? This happens even when I deploy my app ona device. These words are never seen because of this.

Using:

**Unity 5.0.3p1 (32bit)**

But I've had this problem with all version starting from Unity 4.x

[image]
[image]
[image]

My Hierarchy:

[image]

Comment: Are you using any plugins or Editor scripts? It sounds like a problem with the procedural generation of the mesh, so check that when you hit play no values are changed on the Text Mesh inspector, nor the Font's import settings. Better still, try it on an empty project. If the problem prevails, provide a better picture. If the 3D text is so small, at least scale it up for the screenshot, because you provide no info on what the text is, and it's impossible to tell if that's a number 3 in a strange font, or lots of text, or a font atlas bug.

Comment: @EmilioMartinez I use no plugins specifically for Text, but I do use Vuforia (Augmented Reality plugin) It does not have any effect on the text for anyone else. I've updated the question as well.

Comment: It almost looks like your entire font material is wrapped to a cube somehow. Do you maybe have some interfering script on the object that tampers with the mesh or something?

Comment: @Reasurria yes it does, and I've updated the question with the Inspector of the 3D Text Object. It shows `Cube Mesh` there, but that's how it comes as default. There's nothing sepcific for Words/Text.

Comment: I wish I can recall better. What happens if you change it to a plane instead of a cube?

Comment: @Reasurria its still a problem, only we see one side of the disfigured cube (Plane). Any other ideas?

Comment: Wait I just noticed you are putting a text mesh on a UI element. Is this intentional? I don't think that will work correctly. I think either go with the normal UI text in the new UI system or only use the text mesh.

Comment: It's not a UI element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is having a `MeshFilter` on the same `GameObject` as your `TextMesh`

What you are seeing is the `MeshRenderer` drawing the wrong mesh, but using the font's material. Those seemingly random letters is what a *font texture atlas* actually looks like when textured on a cube. What mesh is chosen might as well be random, and with bad luck this kind of things might go undetected on the editor but show up on the builds.

This situation has already been submitted as an issue, but marked as *Status By Design*. Quoting directly from the [issue tracker page](http://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/text-renders-through-solid-bodies):

> TextMesh mesh is wrong when MeshFilter present on same GameObject.
>
> This is expected behavior.
>
> MeshFilter and TextMesh are both components that rely on a
>   MeshRenderer component to render the mesh. When they are both present,
>   they are conflicting over which one gets to set the mesh that the
>   MeshRenderer should use.
>
> That said, we should not allow a MeshFilter and TextMesh on the same
>   GameObject because it is not supported anyway. We'll file a separate
>   bug bug on that.

Comment: Just tried it. Worked like a charm. Removed `MeshFilter` from my `3D Text` and it doesn't become that cube anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I think the RectTransform is messing things up. Right click and save the settings of your text mesh. Then use the menus at the top of Unity to add a new, clean 3D text mesh and paste the component settings into that one. Don't choose the UI text if you want to use the 3D text. There is a separate option for the 3D text.

Comment: That is precisely what my text already is. It's not an Empty object which I have added components into. I've simply gone into `3D Object` > `3D Text`

Comment: Oh I see. Those anchors and pivots are suspicious though. I could've sworn the 3D text comes with a normal transform. Can you add a screenshot of the tree structure of your scene?

Comment: Info added. Please check the question again.

Comment: At this point I'm just taking guesses to be honest. Can you try constructing it from an empty object and preserve the standard transform component? One theory I have is that the RectTransform is looking for a parent UI/canvas to determine its own transform.

Comment: Just tried it. It's all fine when I place it, even with the current one. But the moment I play with it and put it up on a device. Its cubes up on me. Vote up the question then. Might attract more people to answer. :)